# Summing calculated fields in access

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have generated an access report that shows the process comments  for the different locations we have in the organization. What I need to do is to count the total number of comments we have per day for the daily report I generated.

I used a textbox  under the gourp footer with the expresson "=Count([Comment])". It worked fine to get the count of teh comments under each goroup.

I need to gererate a grand total for the report summing the values of the textbox with the above expression.

Also, is there a way to count the text fields one time as a grand total for the report.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it just like you did with the group footer box.  Just set the property to Over All instead of over group.